# iOS Core Data NSRangeException

Tags: ios, json, core-data, nsrangeexception

I have an issue I cant solve. Im creating an iOS application with Core Data framework. Everything was going just fine until I got NSRangeException. This exception I get in function which checks if Application data needs to be updated.

My code is:

```
- (BOOL) isTimetableUpdatedWithJSONData:(NSMutableDictionary*) data
{
    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    //Do database update check logic here
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MobileTimetableDataHash"     inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (error != nil)
    {
        [self printErrorAlert];
    }
    //THERE IS ERROR HERE
    NSManagedObject* changesGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *changesFromDatabase = [changesGrabbed valueForKey:@"changes"];
    NSString *changesFromService = [data valueForKeyPath:@"changes"];

    if ([changesFromService isEqualToString:changesFromDatabase])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [changesGrabbed setValue:changesFromService forKey:@"changes"];

        [managedObjectContext save:&error];

        if (error != nil)
        {
            [self printErrorAlert];
        }
        return NO;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
2014-06-12 21:36:12.034 MIF[437:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for     empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101cb3495 __exceptionPreprocess +     165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101a1299e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c6be3f -[__NSArrayI     objectAtIndex:] + 175
3   MIF                                 0x0000000100001942 -[MIFTimetableService     isTimetableUpdatedWithJSONData:] + 514
4   MIF                                 0x000000010000219d -[MIFAppDelegate     synchrinizeTimetableService] + 157
5   MIF                                 0x0000000100001dc2 -[MIFAppDelegate     application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 114
6   UIKit                               0x00000001005ba3d9 -[UIApplication     _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 264
7   UIKit                               0x00000001005babe1 -[UIApplication     _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1605
8   UIKit                               0x00000001005bea0c -[UIApplication     _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
9   UIKit                               0x00000001005cfd4c -[UIApplication     handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
10  UIKit                               0x00000001005d0216 -[UIApplication     sendEvent:] + 79
11  UIKit                               0x00000001005c0086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent     + 578
12  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103ce671a _PurpleEventCallback +     762
13  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103ce61e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c35679     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c3544e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 +    478
16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c5e903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c5dd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific +     467
18  UIKit                               0x00000001005be2e1 -[UIApplication _run] +     609
19  UIKit                               0x00000001005bfe33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
20  MIF                                 0x0000000100001d23 main + 115
21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010234b5fd start + 1
22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Guys, can anyone help me please? I realy need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Tap checkmark below vote count of an answer to make it accepted, don't add "solved" to title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your troublemaker seems to be

> NSManagedObject* changesGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:0];

If *results* is an empty array, calling *objectAtIndex:0* will cause a NSRangeException, because **there is no** object at index 0. You better call [results firstObject], which won't crash with an error if results is empty array. firstObject() just returns nil in this case.

Comment: Got to watch out though, since you'll be sending messages to nil, which will cause issues farther down the line unless there is an explicit check for the existence of an object before sending it messages

Comment: But can you tell me, why this error may be empty? May it happen because Im trying to reach empty database?

Comment: It's probably because the NSFetchRequest you're executing is not returning any matching objects. This is expected behavior, I presume. You're checking if an Error is present ( != nil ), but this Error is only returned if there is an actual problem executing the request, and not something that is found when there are no results

Comment: Problem was that I was trying to update database with test data at the beginning. My function used to find test data and update it. When I moved Appication to another Mac, there were no test data to update and application crashed. Tha/nk you guys very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to retrieve an object from an empty array. You should first check to see if the array contains any objects. Use the `count` property:

```
if (results.count > 0) {
    NSManagedObject* changesGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    //continue...
} else {
    //Array is empty, object 0 will be beyond bounds
}
```

Comment: You edited your question with the word "Solved" in the title but you didn't check an answer as accepted. You should do this so that the person who answered you correctly gets notified and a reputation bonus.

Comment: Sorry, Im new here :).

Answer (score 1):

Just before

```
NSManagedObject* changesGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:0];
```

Add a branch based on the returned results. Something like the following:

```
if (results && [results count] > 0) {
    NSManagedObject* changesGrabbed = [results objectAtIndex:0];
    ...
}
```

Your array is empty. The stacktrace pretty much spells it out for you --

> reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for
>   empty array'

Comment: There's no need to check `results` twice; `if ([results count] > 0) ...` would be sufficient.

Comment: My example was a bit pedantic, yes. However, I suppose it saves the cost of a message dispatch, method invocation, and comparison (at the cost of an initial comparison).